# Azure Function App - Configure "Deployment Center" with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I'm attempting to setup an Azure Function App with Terraform.

The azurerm_windows_function_app_function resource allows a script to be created directly from the terraform configuration. However, for some reason, changing the file content requires the app function to be re-created. This makes it unusable, because the destroy/re-create errors.

In the portal it's possible to configure a functions code to be deployed via SCM. However I can't find a way to configure the "Deployment Center" via Terraform.

Is there any way to automate the configuration of a Function App's "Deployment Center". Terraform would be ideal, but if it can be done with ARM, or even a cli command, that should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct, way to configure SCM or Source control in [**azurerm_windows_function_app**](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_function_app) terraform provider. The Source control block is present in [**azurerm_function_app**](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app#example-usage-python-in-a-consumption-plan) provider.

You can refer my [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76432127/azures-function-app-not-being-able-to-access-storage-account/76437214#76437214) to deploy Function Code via Storage account as zip via storage account URL.

My main.tf:-

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.59.0"
    }
  }
}


provider "azurerm" {
  
subscription_id = "xxxx4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7"
tenant_id = "xxxxce4-99ed-af9038592395"
client_id = "xxxxx8-6d26a31435cb"
client_secret = "xxxxxRt8313-CS0ifbLE"
features {
  resource_group {
    prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
  }
}

}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "azure-functions-example-rgsiddhesh"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "examlpesasiliconstrg32"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "azure-functions-example-sp-siliconweb"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  kind                = "Linux"
  reserved            = true
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]

  sku {
    tier = "Dynamic"
    size = "Y1"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      kind
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
  name                       = "example-azure-function-siliconfunc65"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  os_type                    = "linux"
  version                    = "~4"
  depends_on = [ azurerm_storage_account.example ]
  app_settings = {
      "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" = "python",
    "AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage" = "true",
    "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT" =  "true"
  }
  site_config {
    linux_fx_version = "python|3.10"
  }
  source_control {
    repo_url = "https://github.com/username/functionrepo"
    branch = "main"
  }
}
```

You can also create a github action workflow via Azure CLI command from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/deployment/github-actions?view=azure-cli-latest) like below:-

Command:-

```bash
az functionapp deployment github-actions add --repo "sid24desai/funchttp" --branch main -g siliconrg5 -n siliconfunc32 --token github_pat_xxxxxxxxYA5UEkAZqq
```

**Output:-**

[image]

You can run the same command in your terraform script like below:-

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.62.1"
    }
  }
}


provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "azure-functions-example-rgsiddhesh"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "eeeesasiliconstrg32"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "eeesiliconweb"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  kind                = "Linux"
  reserved            = true
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]

  sku {
    tier = "Dynamic"
    size = "Y1"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      kind
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
  name                       = "eesiliconfunc65"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  os_type                    = "linux"
  version                    = "~4"
  depends_on = [ azurerm_storage_account.example ]
  app_settings = {
      "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" = "python",
    "AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage" = "true",
    "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT" =  "true"
  }
  site_config {
    linux_fx_version = "python|3.10"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "run_az_cli" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az functionapp deployment github-actions add --repo sid24desai/funchttp --branch main -g resourcegroupname -n function-name --token github_pat_xxxxxxxxA5UEkAZqq"
  }
}
```

This command will create a new workflow file in your repository, Just replace the Function app name with your Function and run the workflow:-

[image]

[image]