# azurerm_linux_function_app - Configure "Deployment Center" with Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-functions, terraform-provider-azure

Trying to configure the SCM with the Azure Function app (Linux based) using Terraform. I am able to do this using Azure Function App console by adding an ExternalGit but facing difficulty in finding the way to implement using Terraform.

Gone through the Azure terraform documentation and it's not giving any hint or reference on how to configure it and which arguments will it support.[This is what I want to implement using terraform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adZvA.png)

I have to pass this terraform to client so that they can easily deploy the application without configuring all this manually.

Below is the resource block in which I want to add SCM configuration:

````
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function-app" {
  name                       = "function-app-${random_string.function_app_suffix.result}"
  location                   = var.location
  resource_group_name        = var.ise_resource_group
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.ise-asp.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.ise-app-storage.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.ise-app-storage.primary_access_key

  app_settings = {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage"            = azurerm_storage_account.ise-app-storage.primary_connection_string
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" = azurerm_application_insights.func-appinsights.instrumentation_key
    "AppConfigConnectionString"      = azurerm_app_configuration.ise_appconf.primary_read_key[0].connection_string
  }

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      python_version = "3.10"
    }
  }
}```


Tried adding arguments related to source_block and also tried using below resource blocks 
 resource "azurerm_source_control_token" and 
 resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control" bud it didn't work.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer my [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76549059/azure-function-app-configure-deployment-center-with-terraform/76555151#76555151) here for the same ask. By default - [azurerm_linux_function_app](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_function_app) does not contain source_control block it is available in [azurerm_function_app](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app) which is now deprecated but you can still use it for your terraform deployment.

***Below code referred from my SO thread answer:-***

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.59.0"
    }
  }
}


provider "azurerm" {
  
subscription_id = "xxxxx2a7"
tenant_id = "xxxxed-axxx"
client_id = "xxxxxxb"
client_secret = "xxxxxxx-xxxxLE"
features {
  resource_group {
    prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
  }
}

}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "azure-functions-example-rgsiddhesh"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "examlpesasiliconstrg32"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "azure-functions-example-sp-siliconweb"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  kind                = "Linux"
  reserved            = true
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]

  sku {
    tier = "Dynamic"
    size = "Y1"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      kind
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
  name                       = "example-azure-function-siliconfunc65"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  os_type                    = "linux"
  version                    = "~4"
  depends_on = [ azurerm_storage_account.example ]
  app_settings = {
      "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" = "python",
    "AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage" = "true",
    "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT" =  "true"
  }
  site_config {
    linux_fx_version = "python|3.10"
  }
  source_control {
    repo_url = "https://github.com/sid24desai/funchttp"
    branch = "main"
  }
}
```

[image]

As a workaround you can use **`az cli`** command to deploy the function with remote/local git or directly via git repository refer the code below:-

**Script reference:-**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.59.0"
    }
  }
}


provider "azurerm" {
  
subscription_id = "0151c365-f598-44d6-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7"
tenant_id = "xxxxaf90xxxx"
client_id = "xxxxxa31435cb"
client_secret = "xxxxxxx"
features {
  resource_group {
    prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
  }
}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "siliconrgsid09"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "linuxfuncsilicon63"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "silicon-appsrvc92"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "Y1"
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "example" {
  name                = "silicon-funcapp94"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location

  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.example.id
  depends_on = [ azurerm_storage_account.example ]
    app_settings = {
      "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" = "python",
    "AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage" = "true",
    "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT" =  "true"
  }
  site_config {
      application_stack {
        python_version = "3.10"
      }
  
}


}

resource "null_resource" "run_az_cli" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az functionapp deployment source config --branch main --manual-integration --name  ${azurerm_linux_function_app.example.name} --repo-url https://github.com/sid24desai/functionpyhttp --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.example.name}"
  }
}
```

As a workaround you can my another [SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76432127/azures-function-app-not-being-able-to-access-storage-account/76437214#76437214) to Deploy Function trigger inside Function app via Storage account.

Comment: I have raised a feature request at Terraform for this. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/23401#issuecomment-1739253470